# Android Error connecting to a database on remote server

Tags: java, android

I am trying to connect my android application to a database on a remote server.
I created a login form but it shows the following error.

```
02/11 21:14:24: Launching app
No apk changes detected since last installation, skipping installation of C:\Users\manav\AndroidStudioProjects\MySQLConnect\app\build\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk
$ adb shell am force-stop com.example.mysqlconnect
$ adb shell am start -n "com.example.mysqlconnect/com.example.mysqlconnect.MainActivity" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Connected to process 31621 on device xiaomi-redmi_note_3-dbdeee7e
Capturing and displaying logcat messages from application. This behavior can be disabled in the "Logcat output" section of the "Debugger" settings page.
W/System: ClassLoader referenced unknown path: /data/app/com.example.mysqlconnect-1/lib/arm64
D/AccessibilityManager: current package=com.example.mysqlconnect, accessibility manager mIsFinalEnabled=false, mOptimizeEnabled=false, mIsUiAutomationEnabled=false, mIsInterestedPackage=false
D/OpenGLRenderer: Use EGL_SWAP_BEHAVIOR_PRESERVED: true
I/Adreno: QUALCOMM build                   : a7823f5, I59a6815413
    Build Date                       : 09/23/16
    OpenGL ES Shader Compiler Version: XE031.07.00.00
    Local Branch                     : mybranch22028469
    Remote Branch                    : quic/LA.BR.1.3.3_rb2.26
    Remote Branch                    : NONE
    Reconstruct Branch               : NOTHING
I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
E/HAL: hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
    hw_get_module_by_class: module name gralloc
I/Timeline: Timeline: Activity_launch_request time:71856102
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x559d757b20 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x559d759ed0
I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: com.android.okhttp.TcmIdleTimerMonitor
D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllStagingAnimators on 0x559d874d50 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x559d89f8a0
W/System.err: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:328)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.SocketConnector.connectTls(SocketConnector.java:103)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connect(Connection.java:143)
        at com.android.okhttp.Connection.connectAndSetOwner(Connection.java:185)
W/System.err:     at com.android.okhttp.OkHttpClient$1.connectAndSetOwner(OkHttpClient.java:128)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.nextConnection(HttpEngine.java:342)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:331)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:249)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.execute(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:437)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.connect(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:114)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:245)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.getOutputStream(DelegatingHttpsURLConnection.java:218)
        at com.android.okhttp.internal.huc.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:25)
        at com.example.mysqlconnect.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:52)
        at com.example.mysqlconnect.BackgroundTask.doInBackground(BackgroundTask.java:23)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:295)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:234)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertificateException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:     at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:324)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.TrustManagerImpl.checkServerTrusted(TrustManagerImpl.java:225)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.Platform.checkServerTrusted(Platform.java:115)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.verifyCertificateChain(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:556)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.NativeCrypto.SSL_do_handshake(Native Method)
        at com.android.org.conscrypt.OpenSSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(OpenSSLSocketImpl.java:324)
        ... 20 more
    Caused by: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.
W/System.err:   ... 26 more
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b7340e
V/BoostFramework: BoostFramework() : mPerf = com.qualcomm.qti.Performance@b19e2f
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.mysqlconnect, PID: 31621
    android.view.WindowManager$BadTokenException: Unable to add window -- token android.os.BinderProxy@965df6d is not valid; is your activity running?
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.setView(ViewRootImpl.java:584)
        at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:313)
        at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:86)
        at android.app.Dialog.show(Dialog.java:322)
        at com.example.mysqlconnect.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:134)
        at com.example.mysqlconnect.BackgroundTask.onPostExecute(BackgroundTask.java:23)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.finish(AsyncTask.java:651)
        at android.os.AsyncTask.access$500(AsyncTask.java:180)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$InternalHandler.handleMessage(AsyncTask.java:668)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5604)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 31621 SIG: 9
Application terminated.
```

Following are my Java files.

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.example.mysqlconnect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    EditText ET_NAME,ET_PASS;
    String login_name,login_pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ET_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_name);
        ET_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.user_pass);
    }

    public void userReg(View view) {
        startActivity(new Intent(this,Register.class));
    }

    public void userLogin(View view) {
        login_name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
        login_pass = ET_PASS.getText().toString();
        String method = "login";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,login_name,login_pass);
    }
}
```

**BackgroundTask.java**

```
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String> {
    AlertDialog alertDialog;
    Context ctx;

    BackgroundTask(Context ctx) {
        this.ctx =ctx;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(ctx).create();
        alertDialog.setTitle("Login Information....");
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String reg_url = "https://snipy.unaux.com/MySQLDemo/register.php";
        String login_url = "https://snipy.unaux.com/MySQLDemo/login.php";
        String method = params[0];

        if (method.equals("register")) {
            String name = params[1];
            String user_name = params[2];
            String user_pass = params[3];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(reg_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);

                //httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream OS = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(OS, "UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("user", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                        URLEncoder.encode("user_pass", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(user_pass, "UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                OS.close();
                InputStream IS = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                IS.close();
                //httpURLConnection.connect();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();
                String string= new String("Registration Success...");

                return string;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else if(method.equals("login")) {
            String login_name = params[1];
            String login_pass = params[2];
            try {
                URL url = new URL(login_url);
                HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
                httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
                OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
                BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream,"UTF-8"));
                String data = URLEncoder.encode("login_name","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_name,"UTF-8")+"&"+
                    URLEncoder.encode("login_pass","UTF-8")+"="+URLEncoder.encode(login_pass,"UTF-8");
                bufferedWriter.write(data);
                bufferedWriter.flush();
                bufferedWriter.close();
                outputStream.close();

                InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
                BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream,"iso-8859-1"));
                String response = "";
                String line  = "";
                while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
                    response+= line;
                }
                bufferedReader.close();
                inputStream.close();
                httpURLConnection.disconnect();

                return response;
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        if (result =="Registration Success...") {
            Toast.makeText(ctx, result, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        } else {
            alertDialog.setMessage(result);
            alertDialog.show();
        }
    }
}
```

**Register.java**

```
package com.example.mysqlconnect;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class Register extends Activity {
    EditText ET_NAME,ET_USER_NAME,ET_USER_PASS;
    String name,user_name,user_pass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register_layout);

        ET_NAME = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.name);
        ET_USER_NAME= (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_name);
        ET_USER_PASS = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.new_user_pass);
    }

    public void userReg(View view) {
        name = ET_NAME.getText().toString();
        user_name = ET_USER_NAME.getText().toString();
        user_pass =ET_USER_PASS.getText().toString();
        String method = "register";
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(this);
        backgroundTask.execute(method,name,user_name,user_pass);
        finish();
    }
}
```

Please, help... I am stuck in here for a long time and if you could give any resources on how to connect an android app to a database on the server using MySQL and PHP it would be highly appreciable.

Comment: You are trying to access `HTTPS` protocol, try changing it to http (If your domain allows it) or change `java.net.HttpUrlConnection` to `javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://snipy.unaux.com/

This website ssl certificate is not trusted by the system.

You can according okhttp doc trust your certificate.

Or you can replace https with http to solve this problem for now.

String reg_url = "http://snipy.unaux.com/MySQLDemo/register.php";

String login_url = "http://snipy.unaux.com/MySQLDemo/login.php";

Answer (score 0):

Check to see if the url is http or https then change your connection from http to https:

```
URL url = new URL(reg_url);
HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

if (reg_url.startsWith("https://") {
    SSLSocketFactory socketFactory = (SSLSocketFactory) SSLSocketFactory.getDefault();
    ((HttpsURLConnection) httpURLConnection).setSSLSocketFactory(socketFactory);
}

httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Do the same for Login.